# Does aghanim scepter upgrade applies on already casted spells?

Tags: dota-2

I was using ancient apparition and cast my ultimate, I bought scepter right after the ice blast projectile launched. Does it apply the scepter upgrade or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. I tried a similar situation with Sniper. Cast ultimate, courier brought me Aghanim Scepter and my ulti was still without bonus. I don't see reason to apply bonus on already channeled/casted spells or abilities.

It is same as when you upgrade your already channeled{casted spell or ability. Good example is Spirit Breaker and his charged. When he already cast charge and he upgrade this ability he will not increase his speed.